# How to do a deep copy of an entire tbody, append it under a different table, and use all of its JS functions?

Tags: javascript, lodash, deep-copy

I would like to deep copy a table TBODY on a button click and make it appear under a different table on the webpage. I cannot shallow copy as there are buttons inside the cells with multiple functions, which I would like to use in the copied tbody and have them apply only to the copied items. I have downloaded and referenced lodash in my HTML file as I heard it is much simpler to deep copy with it. The problem here is I don't know how to apply it as an onclick function.

My code is a mess as there are so many different functions at play, so I won't upload it here. I think I will prepare a shortened version.

```
<table id="my-table">
  <tbody id="my-tbody">
    <tr>
     <td>Example text</td>
     <td><input type="text" id="input-text" onkeydown="keyDown()"></td>
     <td>Example text</td>
     <td><button id="check-btn" type="button" 
      onclick="checkInput()">check</button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, the buttons inside the tds, as well as the input field, all have their own individual functions. Now, I would like to deep copy the entire tbody on a button click and make it appear here:

```
<table id="my-table2>
<tr>


</tr>
</table>
```

I used this to shallow copy the tbody:

```
<button type="button" onclick="duplicate()">example-btn</button>

function duplicate() {
var itm = document.getElementById("my-tbody");
var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
document.getElementById("my-table2").appendChild(cln);
}
```

... and it works fine, the problem is, the cloned buttons affect the original cells.

Like I said, I have downloaded `lodash` and would like to utilize the `_.cloneDeep()` function, but I have no clue how to do that. Some questions:

1) Is it possible to deep clone using just pure JS?
2) Can I use `_.cloneDeep()` on a button click? If yes, how could I achieve that?

Thank you for your time and replies. This is really important for my project! :)

Comment: Have you considered using custom elements? Though they won't be supported by older browsers. They're essentially designed for reusable HTML + JS + CSS tuples.

Comment: Is not the buttons what affect the original elements but the **in-line listeners** (functions like `keyDown` from your example). You'll have to change these functions so that they will take into consideration the elements that call them.

Comment: What I meant by saying that (shallow) copied buttons affect the original content is that they do their intended functions (e.g. they check whether the input is correct/false/empty) but only to the original <tbody>. Example: I wrote "yes" into the original input and then clicked a copied button with checkInput() function, the function works but instead of displaying a message next to the copied <td> it shows it next to the original <td> from the first table.

Comment: I think that `_.cloneDeep` is for plain JS objects, not for DOM nodes (they're also JS objects, but they correspond to HTML elements...)

Comment: @FZs do you have any idea what I could do to clone those tbodies or rows on click?

I mean... I could include all of the rows in the HTML file, make them "display: none" and then use the button click to change their display to "table-row" but I think it would take thousands of thousands of lines to make it work and seems highly inefficient.

Comment: when you clone you also copy the id's, i'm guessing you're using those id's in your functions. Perhaps change id's to classes (to prevent other issues like with css etc) and use the *this* and *siblings* to get the correct input